# What happens when a duplicate value is inserted in a Map in C++

Tags: c++

```
void main()
{

    std::map<int,int>keyValueMap;
    keyValueMap.insert(0,1);
    keyValueMap.insert(0,2);

    int index = keyValueMap.begin()->second;

}
```

the value of index at thispoint is 1 and not 2 can someone explain why ?

Comment: You could have read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) for this

Comment: This is perfectly explained in the docs.

Comment: You should do at least some basic research before asking questions here.

Comment: I thought i will get a detailed explanation here as why it is allowed in Java and not C++. There is no need for you to be rude @davmac

Comment: @Divya I think you have misinterpreted my suggestion. It was not intended to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the 2-param overloads of [`std::map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) require iterators, not key/value pairs.

Most standard container `insert()` methods take the container's `value_type` as input. The `value_type` of a `std::map` is a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). So, when inserting a key/value pair into a `std::map`, you have to pass them in to `insert()` as a `std::pair`, eg:

```
void main()
{
    std::map<int,int> keyValueMap;

    keyValueMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
    keyValueMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, 2));

    int index = keyValueMap.begin()->second;
}
```

Now, that being said, the second `insert()` will still not overwrite the value from the first `insert()`, even though they both have the same key `0`. The second insert will simply be ignored:

> Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.**
>
> ...
>
> Return value
>
> 1-3) Returns a pair consisting of an `iterator` to the inserted element (**or to the element that prevented the insertion**) and a `bool` denoting whether the insertion took place.

To overwrite the first value with the second value, you can either:

- use the iterator that `insert()` returns:

  ```
  void main()
  {
      std::map<int,int> keyValueMap;

      keyValueMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));

      auto ret = keyValueMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, 2));
      if (!ret.second) ret.first->second = 2;

      int index = keyValueMap.begin()->second;
  }
  ```
- use the map's `operator[]` instead:

  ```
  void main()
  {
      std::map<int,int> keyValueMap;

      keyValueMap[0] = 1;
      keyValueMap[0] = 2;

      int index = keyValueMap.begin()->second;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

From [this `std::map::insert` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, ***if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key***.

<sub>[Emphasis by me]</sub>

You can't use `insert` to overwrite existing data in the map.

Comment: Does this answer the OP's question?  The reference also says "If an exception is thrown by any operation, the insertion has no effect.", which is talking about what does _not_ happen.   Perhaps your answer is simply, "an exception is thrown" ?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN That's kind of the point, *nothing happens* if you try to insert something which already exists in the map.

Comment: So, not even an exception is thrown.